# How to dynicamlly center the center of a div based on screen size

Tags: javascript, css

I really thought this would be simple but i'm losing my mind!  I just simple want to center a div in the div of the screen.  But not that top left of the div to the center of the screen but the center of the div in the center.

Here is my div css

```
.box
{
    padding-top:20px;
    padding-left:5px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    background-color: rgba(221,221,221,0.5);
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 25px;
    filter: alpha(opacity=90);
    height: 125px;
    width: 250px;
    z-index: 1;
}

<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div id="box"><div>
</form>
```

Thanks!  I couldnt figure out how to get the html to side in a code block.  This is center horizontally and vertically.

Comment: margin:auto will get it centered horizontally

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use position:absolute if you need it centred both horizontally and vertically:

```
#box {
    position:absolute; 
    top:0; left:0; right:0; bottom:0; 
    margin:auto;
    /* etc */
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wcFMw/

Comment: Worked like a charm

Answer (score 4):

**To center horizontally:**

```
margin:auto;
```

**To center vertically:**

```
position: absolute;
top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
```

You could also use `position: fixed` to make the div centered even when scrolling the page.

Also note that you'll have to use `#` instead of `.` to select by **id**. `.` is the CSS selector used for **class**.

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HXBHM/1/)

Comment: that's only horizontally centered - I believe the OP wants it vertically centered too.

Comment: That'll make it initially centered, but note that if the page content results in scrolling the `div` will scroll up the page too.  To get around that the `position` has to be `fixed` instead of `absolute`

Answer (score 0):

```
margin:0 auto;
```

Add this property to your css class.

Comment: This is a declaration, to be precise.